# How can I use for-loop to create automated NBA stat web crawling code for many seasons?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Good morning!
Now I am working on making NBA stats data frame to analyze players' stats by seasons.
For now, I successfully made code to automatically make dataframes by seasons.
However, the problem that I'm working on is that I can save a season of dataframe as a single xlsx file (ex: data_2001.xlsx, data_2002.xlsx, ..... data_2022.xlsx) but I want to make it into **"one"** xlsx file that contains many seasons using for-loop. (ex: data_2001~2022.xlsx)

```
years = [2001,2002]

for y in years:
    # Season
    url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_{}_advanced.html'.format(y)
    html = urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

    soup.findAll('tr',limit=2)
    # use getText()to extract the text we need into a list
    headers = [th.getText() for th in soup.findAll('tr',limit=2)[0].findAll('th')]
    # exclude the first column as we will not need the ranking order from Basketball Reference for the analysis
    headers = headers[1:]
    
    rows = soup.findAll('tr')[1:]
    player_stats = [[td.getText() for td in rows[i].findAll('td')] for i in range (len(rows))]
    stats = pd.DataFrame(player_stats, columns = headers)


    
    stats['Year'] = y             #Added column ['Year'] to recognize season in the dataframe  
    stats['Season_type'] = 'RS'.  #Added column ['Season_type'] to recognize season type in the dataframe  
    stats = stats.apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='ignore') # changed object data types to float to maniupulate data
    stats = stats[stats['G']>=57]                #Only players who played more than 70% of games
    stats = stats.drop(stats.columns[[18,23]],axis=1) # drop NAN columns

  
    print(f'Finished scraping data for the {y}.')
    lag = np.random.uniform(low=5,high=10)
    print(f'...waiting {round(lag,1)} seconds')
    time.sleep(lag)
    
    y_str = str(y)
    stats.to_excel('data_'+y_str+'.xlsx', index=False). # save as xlsx file
```

And the outputs for this code is making data2001.xlsx and data2002.xlsx

```
data_2001 = pd.read_excel('data2001.xlsx')
data_2002 = pd.read_excel('data2002.xlsx')
```

[For data_2001](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwmCG.png)
[For data_2002](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXtGd.png)

But what I want to make is one xlsx file that contains lots of seasons.
What changes should I give to my for-loop?
Thank you for helping me!!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace the last line, where you are saving each dataframe with an append, so each loop appends each dataframe containing a season (in your loop) to a list that will then pass to [pd.concat()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html). Right before the loop you can do:

```
season_df = []
for y in years:
   #no need to change anything here until
   #...
   print(f'Finished scraping data for the {y}.')
   lag = np.random.uniform(low=5,high=10)
   print(f'...waiting {round(lag,1)} seconds')
   time.sleep(lag)
   season_df.append(stats)
#Outside the for loop
all_seasons_df = pd.concat(season_df)
```